# Ошибка с подключаемой библиотекой в C#

Tags: c#

Есть код:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game;
using Terraria;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
sealed class Program : Terraria.Main
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try { Program.game = new Program(); }
        catch { Console.WriteLine("fail, sorry :("); Console.ReadKey();    return; }

        Program.game.Run();
    }
    private SpriteFont font;
    private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    internal Program() : base() { }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        base.LoadContent();

        font = Terraria.Main.fontMouseText;
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        base.Draw(gameTime);
        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.NonPremultiplied);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "Hello World", new Vector2(5f, 5f), Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 1f);
        spriteBatch.End();
    }
}
}
```

Ошибка возникает в строке `using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game;`

Текст ошибки:

> Ошибка    1   Директива использования пространства имен может применяться только для пространств имен; "Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game" является типом, а не пространством имен c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\Program.cs  4   7   ConsoleApplication2

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка говорит о том, что `Game` является классом, а в `using` можно указывать только пространства имен. Так как у вас уже есть объявление  `Microsoft.Xna.Framework`, то просто удалите строчку:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game;
```

В некоторых ситуациях в директиве `using` можно указывать имя класса. Это используется для локального переопределения его имени. Например:

```
using XnaGame = Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game;
```